# Selenium Webdriver :- Element Not Interactable Exception for the search option

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fill in the search input type box with value "fab" and then I want to display the next url with that keyword but I am getting this error for element not interactable. How can I solve this?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\Mansi Dhingra\\Downloads\\chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.thenational.ae/search?q=")
print(driver.title)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="q"]')
print(search_bar)
search_bar.clear()
search_bar.send_keys("fab")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print(driver.current_url)
driver.close()
```

Error:-

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Mansi
> Dhingra/Desktop/Projects/api/news/news_python.py", line 10, in
>
> search_bar.clear()   File "C:\Users\Mansi Dhingra\Desktop\Projects\api\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
> line 95, in clear
> self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)   File "C:\Users\Mansi Dhingra\Desktop\Projects\api\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
> line 633, in _execute
> return self._parent.execute(command, params)   File "C:\Users\Mansi
> Dhingra\Desktop\Projects\api\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 321, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Mansi Dhingra\Desktop\Projects\api\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
> element not interactable   (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.92)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever webelement is found but not ready to interact then webdriver will throw element not intractable exception.

1.Mostly it occurs, when element is located in bottom of the page, so it can be accessible by scrolling the page down. You can use Action class to scroll to scroll to that element

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("my-id"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
## actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

2. Sometimes we need to wait few seconds to access the web element, in such situations we can add wait statements.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))
```

Comment: Actually I am new to selenium. Can you help me by embedding your code into mine because I didn't exactly understood where I have to make changes.

Comment: I have applied wait function and also search is not the last element. Please it would be very helpful if you could help me with appending changes into my code

Comment: Try to add implicit wait statements before the line "search_bar.clear()" and then try